# Create mountable device /dev/sd originated of a directory

Tags: filesystems, directory, devices

From a directory how can we create mountable device `/dev/sd`... (as if usual partition) so simply a virtual device of a directory, by use of command line ?
All must be by script/command line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but probably what you're looking for is `mknod`.

```
sudo mknod sda  b 8 0
sudo mknod sda1 b 8 1
sudo mknod sda2 b 8 2
```